# Toolbar исчезает при переходе на новый Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Есть два фрагмента - RuleListFragmetn и RuleFragment. В фрагменте RuleListFragment используется элемент RecyclerView. Toolbar имеет флаги `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"`, в тоже время AppBarLayout имеет параметр `app:liftOnScroll="true"`. Если список в RuleListFragment не был прокручен и совершен переход на фрагмент RuleFragment, то Toolbar на месте. Если список в RuleListFragment был прокручен (Toolbar скрылся вверху), то при переходе на фрагмент RuleFragment Toolbar пропадает. Картинка ниже объясняет. Может во фрагменте нужно сбросить положение Toolbar? Но как это сделать?

[image: Нажатие на rule # 0, Toolbar виден]

[image: Нажатие на rule # 23, Toolbar не виден]

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы Toolbar, при переходе на другой фрагмент всегда показывался?

Comment: Да, но чтобы у него оставались все те же свойства (scroll, enterAlways, snap). Возможно Toolbar есть во втором фрагменте, просто он наверху, и не виден. Соответственно нужно как-то сбросить его положение, но я не знаю как.

Comment: Не знаю, сработает ли, попробуйте при переходе на другой фрагмент toolbar.setLifted(false);

Comment: Решение вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60789665/toolbar-disappears-upon-transition-to-new-fragment)